# Python, beautifulsoup. Не получается получить весь текст со страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Не получается корректно получить весь текст с одинаковых div'ов
На сайте выглядит так:

```html
<div class="c-gruppedprops__group-props">
  <span class="c-gruppedprops__prop">
    <span class="c-gruppedprops__prop-name">
      Тип прокладки:
    </span>
    <span class="c-gruppedprops__prop-value">
      внутренний
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="c-gruppedprops__prop">
    <span class="c-gruppedprops__prop-name">
      Тип:
    </span>
    <span class="c-gruppedprops__prop-value">
      F/UTP
    </span>
```

В результате должно получиться вот так
Тип прокладки: внутренний
Тип: F/UTP

Пробовал методом find

```
specifications = data.find("div", class_="c-gruppedprops__group").text
```

В итоге получилось только так:
Тип прокладки:внутреннийТип:F/UTP

Comment: print(' '.join(data.stripped_strings))